# Screen unusable on 12.04 - inspirion M5010

Tags: 12.04, screen

My screen died (unreadable content), i dont know why. Tried to use an other screen but same problem there. I am running ubuntu 12.04 on a dell inspirion M5010.

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sHag.jpg

Would appreciate some help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a lot of problem when I have unsupported new graphic card on AMD 8 notebook. Your garbage looking screen I suspect is graphic card problem. From my experience, I have more luck with Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit system rather than 64 system on computer with graphic card problem. Even if the computer is qualified to run Ubuntu 64 bit system. You may want to try running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit from Live DVD or Live USB whether you have 'normal' display then. In my experience, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit first. After success, then I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. On grub menu, I enter 12.04 64 bit through trouble shooting selection with minimal drive (not normal Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit), then select 'special' graphic or so (Sorry I forget the exact term, but you will recognize it when you see it, the only option with graphic), try repair package, try this and that, it did no harm, then Resume boot into 12.04 64 bit. If you manage to come into Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, then go to your System Setting and see whether you may need additional (proprietary) driver. You may also visit your graphic processor manufacturer support site and look for Linux Driver for your graphic cards. After all the try and error, in my case, from garbage screen, finally I got my notebook running normally with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, even upgrade it all the way to Ubuntu 14.04.